# iPhone SDK:Editing XML files

Tags: iphone, xml, editing

Is there any external library using which one can edit and save XML files for an iPhone application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather good way to handle XML on the iPhone is using the KissXML library hosted at http://code.google.com/p/kissxml

Using a DDXMLDocument object will allow you to get the data with `- (NSData *)XMLData`

You can write NSData easily to a file using `writeToURL:atomically:` or `writeToFile:atomically:` as described in the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)