# Editing an xml file from iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch

How do I edit an xml file that is stored online through an iphone application?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this from iPhone app. You have to create a server side file (like in PHP) that will do this editing... you can send request to this file to edit this file on server using iPhone app.

you can send POST and get request to this PHP file refer these links if you are not aware of sending request to server side from iPhone app.

http://www.slideshare.net/llch/using-iphones-nsurlconnection-class-presentation

http://tcninja.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-make-post-request-with-iphone.html

also visit this link - 
[iPhone SDK:Editing XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558339/iphone-sdkediting-xml-files)

Comment: I have very little experience with php and I was wondering if you could give me an example of the server side code that would be needed?